# SQL Convert Rows To Columns

Tags: t-sql, pivot

I know this has been asked a few times before, but I can't find any solution that fits my example.

I currently have a table of user permissions to use certain pages. The table would look like this:

```
UserID    pagename         pageid
-----------------------------------
1         home             1
1         contacts         3
3         home             1
2         links            2
```

How would I generate a table from this data where I have all the page names tabulated as columns and each row of the table is for a User ID, the column values display 0 or 1 based on whether or not the original table had an entry for that particular page, for instance:

```
UserID     home     links    contacts
-------------------------------------
1          1        0        1
2          0        1        0
3          1        0        0
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for formatting ax, I was trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Pivot without Aggregate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343145/tsql-pivot-without-aggregate-function

Comment: Could you please give an example? that page doesn't show how its done using Pivot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Build your table in @t:

```
declare @t as table (UserID int, pagename nvarchar(20), pageid int);
insert into @t values (1,'home',1),(1,'contacts',3),(3,'home',1),(2,'links',2);
```

Pivot it:

```
select UserID, 
    case when home is null then 0 else 1 end as home, 
    case when links is null then 0 else 1 end as links, 
    case when contacts is null then 0 else 1 end as contacts
from @t
pivot (
    max(pageid) for pagename in ([home],[links],[contacts])
) pivotT

UserID      home        links       contacts
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           0           1
2           0           1           0
3           1           0           0
```

Answer (score 0):

To easily transpose columns into rows with its names you should use XML. In my blog I was described this with example: [Link](http://sql-tricks.blogspot.com/2011/04/sql-server-rows-transpose.html)

Comment: that's easy?  Don't click, might hurt you!