# SQL Pivot with String

Tags: sql, pivot

I have two tables in SQL Server: Customer and Address

**Customer Table**:

```
CustomerID  FirstName  LastName
----------- ---------- ----------
1           Andrew     Jackson         
2           George     Washington
```

**Address Table**:

```
AddressID   CustomerID  AddressType City
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------
1           1           Home        Waxhaw     
2           1           Office      Nashville    
3           2           Home        Philadelphia
```

This is the output that I need:

```
CustomerID  Firstname  HomeCity      OfficeCity
----------- ---------- ----------    ----------
1           Andrew     Waxhaw        Nashville
2           George     Philadelphia  Null
```

This is my query, but not getting the right result:

```
SELECT CustomerID, Firstname, HOme as HomeCity, Office as OfficeCity FROM 
   (SELECT C.CustomerID, C.FirstName, A.AddressID, A.AddressType, A.City 
    FROM Customer C, Address A 
    WHERE C.CustomerID = A.CustomerID)as P
PIVOT (MAX(city) FOR AddressType in ([Home],[Office])) as  PVT
```

This is the result that I am getting:

```
CustomerID  Firstname  HomeCity      OfficeCity
----------- ---------- ----------    ----------
1           Andrew     Waxhaw        NULL
1           Andrew     NULL          Nashville
2           George     Philadelphia  Null
```

As you can see Customer 1 is showing up twice in the final result. Is it possible to get only one row per customer?

I looked up this example, but didn't help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267660/sql-query-to-convert-rows-into-columns

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is giving this row because you have `AddressID` in the select list for you subquery "P". So even though you don't have AddressID in you top level select this, the `PIVOT` function is still grouping by it. You need to change this to:

```
SELECT  CustomerID, Firstname, Home as HomeCity, Office as OfficeCity 
FROM    (   SELECT C.CustomerID, C.FirstName, A.AddressType, A.City 
            FROM #Customer C, #Address A 
            WHERE C.CustomerID = A.CustomerID
        ) AS P
        PIVOT 
        (   MAX(city) 
            FOR AddressType in ([Home],[Office])
        ) AS  PVT
```

Although I would be inclined to use an explicit `INNER JOIN` rather than an implicit join between customer and Address.

Comment: Wonderful, that worked! Thanks!! I didn't realize addressID was causing it. I got used to implicit joins, but I will start using INNER JOINs as you have mentioned.

Comment: In this scenario it doesn't make a lot of difference whether implicit or inner joins are used, and there are a number of different discussions about the subject e.g [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins). My personal view is that explicit joins are easier to read, allow for easier change between 'INNER` AND 'OUTER` joins, and also reduce the likely hood of accidental cross joins by missing a where clause.

Answer (score 13):

I would write it like this instead:

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, C.Firstname,
    Home.City as HomeCity,
    Office.City as OfficeCity
FROM Customer C
    LEFT JOIN Address Home
        on Home.CustomerID = C.CustomerID and Home.AddressType = 'Home'
    LEFT JOIN Address Office
        on Office.CustomerID = C.CustomerID and Office.AddressType = 'Office'
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like another good way of doing this without using PIVOT.

Comment: This works well if you don't need to aggregate anything. I had a table with some string columns I unpivoted, normalized, and then used to this to rebuild