# SQL Pivot on Int for String

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, pivot

Trying to manipulate some SQL with a Pivot however what I need to pivot on is text and I cant just get it working.

```
customerID  appointment             appointmentNumber   treatment
9           2014-01-09 09:30:00.000 1                   Osteo F 45
9           2014-01-20 09:00:00.000 2                   Osteo F 45
9           2014-01-30 09:30:00.000 3                   Osteo F 45
9           2014-02-10 09:00:00.000 4                   Osteo F 45
```

What I need is to turn the column "appointmentNumber" into column headers, with the "treatment" shown below...

```
customerID 1 2 3 4 etc...
```

I have always used Pivot tables on strings for numbers (sums, counts) in the past and never on numbers for strings so I am a little lost.

I had a look at [SQL Pivot with String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319562/sql-pivot-with-string) but cant seem to apply this to my own code.

Any ideas?

Comment: show us the code you tried and where you get an error.

Comment: did you try to use the first() function?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose between max/min aggregate functions for a string column. In this case I'd assume appointmentNumber, customerId are unique so the aggregate function isn't really doing anything except taking the first value.

```
select
    *
from
    table t
    pivot (
        max(treatment)
        for appointmentNumber in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
    ) p
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation with `max()`:

```
select customerId,
       max(case when appointmentnumber = 1 then treatement end) as an_1,
       max(case when appointmentnumber = 2 then treatement end) as an_2,
       max(case when appointmentnumber = 3 then treatement end) as an_3,
       max(case when appointmentnumber = 4 then treatement end) as an_4,
       max(case when appointmentnumber = 5 then treatement end) as an_5
from table t
group by customerid;
```

You can also do this using `pivot` if you like.  `max()` works fine on string variables.