# SQL Pivot without using aggregate and without knowing cell values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
 id   Name       Value
 ----------------------
 1    Apple      Mac
 2    Apple      iPad
 1    Microsoft  Surface
 2    Microsoft  XBox
```

I need this:

```
id   Apple      Microsoft
-------------------------
1    Mac        Surface
2    iPad       XBox
```

However I won't always know what the 'Name' or 'Value' column data will be. But it will always be in the same column numbers in my select statement

I've tried using pivot but I can't wrap my head around how this would work without aggregate functions

Comment: Usually you still use an aggregate, but you select something like "Max" and know that nothing is truly being aggregated.

Comment: Such as here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27569551/84206

Comment: Here's another example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10026046/84206

Comment: Note the column headers are the `FOR` clause and the values in the cells are the `Max([Name])`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pivot text columns in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025934/how-to-pivot-text-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: Select ID,Microsoft,Apple
FROM 
(
    select * from Prod
) As Temp
PIVOT
(
    max([value]) 
    FOR [Name] In([Microsoft],[Apple])
) As pt