# Join two Tables with one have columns to rows

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I have a table with this structure:

```
Table 1: ID(PK) | <other columns>
              1 | otherdata
              2 | otherdata
```

the other table, It´s a list of documents (PDF,DOC,etc) with a URL to download. these documents is stored in my network.

```
Table 2: ID | IDDOC |    LINKDOC    | INFO
          1 |   1   | 'http://URL1' | 'Info1'
          1 |   2   | 'http://URL2' | 'Info2'
          2 |   1   | 'http://URL3' | 'Info3'
```

ID is the foreign key for Table 1,IDDOC is a foreign key to a 3rd table (below) that describe the document type:

```
Table 3: IDDOC | Name
            1  | 'Contract'
            2  | 'Notification'
```

I need to generate a query to join these tables and get a similar structure

```
ID | <SomeCollumsTable1> | NameDesc1 | NameURL1 | ... | NameDesc2 | NameURL2
```

Example output:

```
  ID | <SomeCollumsTable1> | ContractDesc | ContractURL   | NotificationDesc | NotificationURL
  1  | otherdata           | 'Info1'      | 'http://URL1' | 'Info2'          | 'http://URL2'
  2  | otherdata           | 'Info3'      | 'http://URL3' | ''               | ''
```

I.E. Generate many pairs Desc/URL as many records exits in "Table3". the sample data have 2 documents types and generate 4 columns.

Currently i have subquerys to each desired document, but sounds very inefficient for me, the query is big and new documents i add in "Table3" need change in the whole query and need to just adjust the Where clause to indicate why IDDOC´s need. (using a IN clause)

Or its better to manipulate this in my application (winforms/vb.net)?

The App generate a report in EXCEL format.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired result.  It will help clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sounds like two easy inner joins, did you already tried that?

Comment: It's probably better to do this with a PIVOT in Excel.   But if you want to do it in SQL, google SQL DYNAMIC PIVOT for examples.

Comment: Sample data added. Using a simple inner join also generate duplicate results, i.e. many "Table1" records for every document type. EXCEL pivot is undesirable because the client cannot use advanced functions.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319562/sql-pivot-with-string The answer there doesn't have the PIVOT automatically change for changes in Table 3. The only way to do that is dynamic SQL, with the incumbent security issues.

Comment: @joaogodinho I posted an answer using a dyamic pivot. Also posted a pivot. Please check. This works!

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below query:

```
DECLARE @qu NVARCHAR(MAX), @pcol NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT   @pcol= COALESCE(@pcol + ',','') + type FROM
 (SELECT Name+N'URL' AS type FROM t3 UNION SELECT Name+N'Desc' AS type FROM t3 ) A

SET @qu=N'Select ID,b,c,'+ @pcol + N' FROM
  (
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.b,t1.c, t2.linkdoc as data,t3.Name +N''URL'' as Type FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
    LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.iddoc=t3.iddoc
    UNION
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.b, t1.c, t2.info as data, t3.Name +N''Desc'' as Type FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
    LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.iddoc=t3.iddoc
  )S
  PIVOT
  (
  MAX(data) 
    FOR Type IN ('+@pcol +N')) AS piv'
EXEC sp_executesql @qu
```

Here's a sql fiddle for you : 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9fb46/1

> **EDIT:explanation added**
>
> So basically I am using `PIVOT`, except that `PIVOT` can be done on a
>   single column , in our case, either on `URL` or `Desc` columns. But we
>   need both these columns to be pivoted,so I used UNION to get both into
>   a single column `data` like below
>
> ```
> SELECT t1.ID, t1.b,t1.c, t2.linkdoc as data,t3.Name +N'URL' as Type FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
> LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.iddoc=t3.iddoc
> UNION
> SELECT t1.ID, t1.b, t1.c, t2.info as data, t3.Name +N'Desc' as Type FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
> LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.iddoc=t3.iddoc
> ```
>
> which I then used in PIVOT like this :
>
> ```
> Select ID,b,c,[ContractURL],[ContractDesc],[NotificationURL],[NotificationDesc]
> FROM
>   (
>       SELECT t1.ID, t1.b,t1.c, t2.linkdoc as data,t3.Name +N'URL' as Type FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
>   LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.iddoc=t3.iddoc
>   UNION
>   SELECT t1.ID, t1.b, t1.c, t2.info as data, t3.Name +N'Desc' as Type FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
>   LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.iddoc=t3.iddoc
>   )S
>   PIVOT
>   (
>   MAX(data) 
>     FOR Type IN ([ContractURL],[ContractDesc],[NotificationURL],[NotificationDesc])
>   )piv
> ```
>
> Now for making this dynamic I calculated all the unique columns from table `t3` like
>
> ```
> SELECT Name+N'URL' AS type FROM t3 UNION SELECT Name+N'Desc' AS type FROM t3
> ```

Comment: Before I upvote, can you add some more explanation to the code?  Personally I've got a pretty good grip on what it's doing, however those that are less familiar with SQL may not.