# SQL Server Select Case Statement with two distinct Value in two Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do a ***Join***.

From ***Items Table*** which has Product Information like 
*ItemID, UpcCode, Facing, ItemNameArabic, ShelfCapacity* everything Except *SERVICETYPE*

Joining to table **Schedule** which has *UpcCode* & *ServiceType.*

As you see in the picture there are two rows for almost the same data except one states the *ServiceType* (Either **VMF** or **SRR** )

What I want is Number of Rows should decrease. If you refer to the picture.
*NESCAFE GOLD 50G* is repeated twice. Once for VMF & SRR. I just want it to appear once by using either approach below

Either it is like 2 Columns [Boolean Columns]

a) VMF Column [If value is VMF then 'Yes' Or Else 'NO']

b) SRR Column [If value is SRR then 'Yes' Or Else 'NO']

**Or**

One Column [**ServiceType**]

Where it checks if it has SRR only SRR appears or else Vmf Appears

In any of the above desired result will decrease my number of Rows

Thank You

[image]

Comment: I think you already seem to have the 1 column approach. Maybe if u added a where clause with servicetype = "VMF" u would filter out the VMFs and quid pro quo with "SRR"..

Comment: I tried that approach. Same thing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  case when vmf is null then 0 else 1 end as vmf, 
case when srr is null then 0 else 1 end as srr, 
UpcCode,date, StoreID
FROM
(SELECT itemid,items.UpcCode, ServiceType, date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY servicetype) AS ROWNUMBER, s.ID as StoreID
           FROM Items join Schedule on Items.upccode= schedule.upccode
) r
PIVOT
(
max (r.rownumber)
FOR r.servicetype IN( [vmf],[srr])
) AS pvt
```

I would like to thank [@nestor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122732/nestor) for the wonderful answer on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768586/sql-convert-rows-to-columns)

Answer (score 1):

You will Not get 1 row per **ItemName** by dealing only **ServiceType** column.

Look at your attachment: you have different data in other columns such as **Facing** and **ShelfCapacity**.

If you want to get 1 row per Item name you have two options:

1. remove the different columns from your query.
2. List item pivot **all** your
   different data to columns.

Comment: Yes I have implemented that

Comment: Thank You, I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think u cud try changing the ServiceType in the Select statement using a Case Statement

```
   SELECT  ItemId,....., ServiceType =
          CASE ServiceTypes
             WHEN 'VMF' THEN 'True'
             WHEN 'SRR' THEN 'False'
             ELSE ''
          END, InLimit, IpConcantenated
        from ....
        where ...
```

If u want a repeat of the column , u cud fetch it twice

```
   SELECT  ItemId,.....,
          ServiceTypeVMF =
          CASE ServiceType
             WHEN 'VMF' THEN 'True'
             WHEN 'SRR' THEN 'False'
             ELSE ''
          END, 
          ServiceTypeSRR =
          CASE ServiceType
             WHEN 'VMF' THEN 'False'
             WHEN 'SRR' THEN 'True'
             ELSE ''
          END, 
          InLimit,
          IpConcantenated
        from ....
        where ...
```

well the earlier case statement would fetch u multiple rows but i think this is what should be ur sql statement if u want to convert rows into columns assuming that there are only 2 rows 'VMF' and 'SNR' as u mentioned

```
with cte as
(select ItemID, Upccode, ..............,
  row_number() over(partition by ItemID, Upccode order by ServiceType) As rn
  ,ServiceType
  ,MinLimit
  ,IsContracted     
from Items)
select ItemID, UpcCode, 
  max(case when rn = 1 then ServiceType end) as ServiceType1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then ServiceType end) as ServiceType2,
  ,MinLimit
  ,IsContracted     
from cte
group by ItemId, UpcCode,.........,MinLimit,IsContracted;
```

Comment: What is InLimit & IpConcantenated

Comment: well InLimit,IPConcatenated are the Columns that i saw in ur image which were following ServiceType that i cud make out from ur image. So it is Select <All the columns before Servicetype>,ServiceType Column,<All the columns after ServiceType> .. that is what InLimit & IpConcantenated are.. I think it is MinLimit, IsContracted.. whoops my bad, i just assumed that yours is a routing database cos we often come across those columns in a routing database.. Anyways dont know if it is my browser but the image that u posted does not have a good resolution on my terminal..

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The Repeat of the Column.
Its still giving me 2 rows of the same product. All I want is ONE Row.
ServiceTypeVMF (TRUE) , ServiceTypeSRR (FALSE)

Comment: well select distinct would work but i think the problem is more than that. the problem seems to be in the join that u have written rather than the service type.. so i think u should relook at ur select query again which is returning 2 rows instead of 1 and possibly then include the Case statement to switch to boolean.

Comment: my bad, select distinct would not work.. u said almost the same data , u did not say same data.. but i do think your problem stems out of the initial select and join that you wrote and i think u can get better help if u posted that join statement and table structure somebody might be able to troubleshoot it.. but now i think i understand the problem better.. u hv servicetype records in rows and u would be wanting to show them in columns instead..

Comment: u said it right... I'm getting it rows. And I want to get in Columns

Comment: Could you post an example of both the tables you wish to join

Comment: i edited my initial query to convert ur rows to columns using CTE. dont know how far it wud go but it wud at least take a jog if not a run.