# Convert SQL cell value to column names in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table shown below:

```
  EmpId     IdType     Id_Number
-------   --------   -----------
 112211     MRN         30013
 112211    Member_Id    40012
 223344     MRN         23432
```

And i want cell values MRN, Member_ID appear as column names in the resulting table as shown below:

```
 EmpId     MRN       Member_Id
 -------   --------   -----------
 112211    30013       40012
 223344    23432       Null
```

I guess i need to use PIVOT. But it requires to use aggregate functions. Since there is no aggregate function to use here, I am not finding any other to accomplish this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straightforward pivot - remember that `MIN()` or `MAX()` can be used as aggregates, even on non numeric columns.

```
SELECT EmpID, MRN, Member_ID
FROM
  Employee
PIVOT 
(
  MIN(ID_Number) FOR
  IDType IN ([MRN], [Member_ID])
)  AS p;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28661/3)

Also, note that it is possible to do this [without Pivot- see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1343174/314291)