# Translate rows to column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a few items in the database in the form as below:

```
ID|ColName|ColValue
-------------------
1 |A      |1testa
1 |B      |1testb
1 |C      |1testc
1 |D      |1testd
2 |A      |2testa
2 |D      |2testd
```

I need data in the form below:

```
ID| A      | B      | C      | D
1 | 1testa | 1testb | 1testc | 1testd
2 | 2testa | NULL   |   NULL | 2testd
```

I have tried using `PIVOT` in `T-SQL` but it takes aggregate function as argument, which I do not want to supply.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: Also this could be worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343145/tsql-pivot-without-aggregate-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [ID] TINYINT
    ,[ColName] CHAR(1)
    ,[ColValue] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [ColName], [ColValue])
VALUES   (1, 'A', '1testa')
        ,(1, 'B', '1testb')
        ,(1, 'C', '1testc')
        ,(1, 'D', '1testd')
        ,(2, 'A', '2testa')
        ,(2, 'D', '2testd');

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource
PIVOT
(
    MAX([ColValue]) FOR [ColName] IN ([A], [B], [C], [D])
) PVT
```

is going to give you this:

[image]

Note, that when you are using the `PIVOT`/`UNPIVOT` clauses, you need to specified the columns (in your case `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`). If you do not want to hard-coded then, you need to build a dynamic pivot using - this can be done building the `T-SQL` statement in a `string` and executing it using `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Ohh so I was thinking what aggregate function should be used. I need to use MAX. thanks!

Comment: @Saksham Yes, you can either use `MIN` or `MAX` when pivoting by strings.