# How to Pivot Without Aggregation

Tags: sql-server

I've been reading on this site as well as Google about how to Pivot my data but can't seem to quite figure it out. I want to be able to pivot without doing any aggregation. My data currently looks like. My sql is:

```
select act, rn
from ##Temp_Outage_Crew
order by act

act         rn
00208763-BC2    AUXO01
00208763-BC2    AUXO03
```

But I want it to look like what is shown below. I now there is a way to PIVOT this data but I can't get it to work.

```
act             rn1        rn2
00208763-BC2    AUXO01     AUX03
```

I have "attempted" to use the row number function but I can't seem to get that to work either.

Comment: The only reason not to aggregate is when there's only value; in such a case using the `max` function on that value would return the value; so though you'd be using aggregation, you'd get the result you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TSQL Pivot without aggregate function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343145/tsql-pivot-without-aggregate-function)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you *must* use an aggregation in the `PIVOT`. `MAX` works on strings, so it's a great option when you have a 1-to-1 relationship.

To get the arbitrary `rn1` and `rn2` columns, it makes sense to use ROW_NUMBER(). Assuming you know the maximum number of values `rn` can have for a particular `act` value, you can do something like:

```
;WITH toc_CTE
     AS (SELECT [act],
                [rn],
                [RowNum] = CONCAT('rn', ROW_NUMBER()
                                          OVER (
                                            PARTITION BY [act]
                                            ORDER BY [rn]))
         FROM   #Temp_Outage_Crew)
SELECT [act],
       [rn1],
       [rn2],
       [rn3],
       [rn4]
FROM   toc_CTE
       PIVOT (MAX([rn])
             FOR [RowNum] IN ([rn1],
                              [rn2],
                              [rn3],
                              [rn4])) pvt
```

If, however, there is no concrete limit on the number of `rn` values per `act`, then you will have to use a [dynamic PIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query).

Comment: That did it. I just couldn't figure out the query syntax. I had tried multiple variations with no luck but the syntax above worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Lisa welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your problem satisfactorily, please consider "accepting" it using the check mark next to the score. This lets other users on the site know the question has a viable solution.