# SQL transpose data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, transpose, unpivot

I need to transpose data that looks like the following.  I don't need to use any aggregate functions, just want to transpose columns to rows.

Current view:

```
Name | Code1 | Code2 | Code3 | Pct1 | Pct2 | Pct3 | Amt1 | Amt2 | Amt3
Name1   123     124     125     50     25     25   1000    1500  1555
Name2    123    124     125     50     25     25   1222    1520  1600
```

What I Need:

```
AccountName   |    Code#   |       Pct   |         Amt
Name1              123             50             1000
Name1              124             25             1500
Name1              125             25             1555
Name2              123             50             1222
Name2              124             25             1520
Name2              125             25             1600
```

if this is possible, could you also include where I would place my joins if I need to use data in a different table?

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and I don't have the permission to create tables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TSQL Pivot without aggregate function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343145/tsql-pivot-without-aggregate-function)

Comment: @TabAlleman this is an UNPIVOT not a Pivot.. there's probably a duplicate out there but this is not it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a neat trick using table valued expression

```
SELECT  [Name], ca.*
From    myTable
        CROSS APPLY (Values 
                (Code1, Pct1, Amt1), 
                (Code2, Pct2, Amt2), 
                (Code3, Pct3, Amt3)
        ) ca([Code#], [Pct], [Amt])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    Name,
    case n when 1 then Code1 when 2 then Code2 when 3 then Code3 end as Code,
    case n when 1 then Pct1  when 2 then Pct2  when 3 then Pct3  end as Pct,
    case n when 1 then Amt1  when 2 then Amt2  when 3 then Amt3  end as Amt
from T cross join (values (1), (2), (3)) multiplier(n)
```

The basic idea is to triplicate the rows and then use `case` to pick out the correct values.