# Reference Columns in diffrent table in from cell values and merge resulst into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2014

I have a table (Area_Data) like this...

```
Area1         Area2         Area3
9118890       9228834       9338890
```

Area1,2,3 are column headers (I simplified Area_Data table for sake of this discussion but it has 12 area columns)

Then I have another table(Area_Offset) like this...

```
Name    Offset  Zone      
P5.3    -4      Area1
P3.3    -4      Area1
P3.4    -4      Area1
P5.4    -4      Area2
P61.1   -9      Area3
P5.1    -4      Area2
P3.1    -4      Area3
```

I'm trying to create a table like

```
Name    Offset  Zone      CalculatedOffset    Area
P5.3    -4      Area1    9118886             9118890       
P3.3    -4      Area1    9118886             9118890       
P3.4    -4      Area1    9118886             9118890       
P5.4    -4      Area2    9228830             9228834       
P61.1   -9      Area3    9338886             9338890
P5.1    -4      Area2    9228830             9228834       
P3.1    -4      Area3    9338886             9338890
```

(Calculated offset is not important I think I know how to create that column if I can get the relevant Area data into this table)

What should Should I be doing to achieve this? 
I tried google led me to some resources mentioning Pivot I attempted this but it didn't turn out right

what i tried was...

```
SELECT *

  FROM Area_Offset,
        Area_Data
  PIVOT
  (
    MAX(Area1)
    FOR
        Area1 IN (Zone)
  ) AS p
```

Then was this discussion [TSQL Pivot without aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343145/tsql-pivot-without-aggregate-function/1343174#1343174) but I couldn't get it too work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `unpivot` not `pivot`.  I like to do this using `outer apply`:

```
select ao.*, (v.area + ao.offset) as CalculatedOffset, v.zone as area
from area_data ad outer apply
     (values (area1, 'area1'), (area2, 'area2'), (area3, 'area3')
     ) v(area, zone) join
     area_offset ao
     on ao.zone = v.zone;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to unpivot, I managed to get it working with unpivot. I'm going to give it a try getting to get it working with outer apply later today

Answer (score 1):

Using Cross Apply also we can do

```
Select 
TT.Name,
TT.Offset,
TT.Zone,  
CONVERT(INT,T.VAL)  - CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(TT.Offset,'-',''))    ,T.VAL 
from  ( 
select COL,VAL 
from @Table1
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('Area1',Area1),
                        ('Area2',Area2),
                        ('Area3',Area3))CS(COL,VAL))T
                        INNER JOIN  @Table2 TT
                        ON T.COL = TT.Zone
```

Comment: @daeden please have a look