# Why is the Max function used when we pivot text columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have just learnt how to Pivot in SQL Server. I was wondering why the `max` function is used when we want to pivot text columns? What's the logic behind this? I understand if it's `Count`, `Sum` etc (because your summing that respective row and column) but I don't understand the logic of using `max` when we have text columns?

For example, my code is:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ( SELECT DATE
               ,SITA
               ,EVENT 
          FROM  [UKRMC].[dbo].[strategy] 
          where datename(year, DATE) = 2018 or datename(year,DATE)=2019
        ) strategy
  PIVOT ( max(EVENT)
          FOR SITA IN ([ABZPD],[BFSPD]
,[BFSZH]
,[BHXPD]
,[BHXZH]
,[BRSZH]
,[BRUPQ] ) piv
```

Comment: It's because an aggregate function **has** to be used. In many cases there is only one value, `max` selects that one record, while still following pivot syntax rules.

Comment: As an aside `where datename(year, DATE) = 2018 or datename(year,DATE)=2019` isn't ideal, as it could result in a [non-SARGable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799584/314291) query plan, i.e. any potential indexes on column `DATE` won't be hit.

Comment: It would be desirable to have something like a `SINGLE_VALUE` aggregate in SQL for precisely these situations!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in your example you've chosen `EVENT` as the value to show in the PIVOT intersections (i.e. since you've specified `EVENT` in the `PIVOT` clause), the value must be specified with one of the [permissible aggregate functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql), as there are potentially multiple rows for each of the column values that you've chosen in your pivot, when grouped by the remaining columns (i.e. DATE in your case).

In Sql Server<sup>[1]</sup>, `MAX()` or `MIN()` is commonly used when pivoting non-numeric columns, as it is able to show one of the original of the values of the column.

Any non-aggregate and non-pivoted columns will be left as-is and will be used to form the groups on which the pivot is based (in your case, column `DATE` isn't either in the aggregate, or the column pivot, so it will form the row group)

Consider the case where your pivoted table contains multiple rows matching your predicate, such as this:

```
INSERT INTO strategy (DATE, SITA, EVENT) VALUES
('1 Jan 2018', 'ABZPD', 'Event1'),
('1 Jan 2018', 'BFSPD', 'Event2'),
('1 Jan 2018', 'BFSPD', 'Event3');
```

After Pivot:

```
DATE                    ABZPD   BFSPD
2018-01-01T00:00:00Z    Event1  Event3
```

i.e. During the Pivot, the `BFSPD` rows for `Event2` and `Event3` needed to somehow be projected into a single cell - hence the need for an aggregate. This aggregate is still needed, even if there is known to be just [one value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1343145/314291) (this being the case for the `Event1` value for SITA `ABZPD` in the above example).

Since `BFSPD` has two events, you'll need to somehow resolve how to project a value into a single cell value. The use of `MAX` on the VARCHAR column resolves the 'largest' value (`Event3`) in the event of multiple rows in projecting into the same resulting pivot 'cell' - [SqlFiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd713/12)

You could choose to use `COUNT(Event)` to show you the number of events per row / pivot intersection - [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd713/15)

And you could switch the aggregate on `EVENT` with `DATE` - `EVENT` is thus used in the [column grouping](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd713/18).

---

<sub>*1 Aggregates like `AVG` or `STDEV` are obviously not available to strings. Other RDBMS have additional aggregates like [FIRST](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm) which will arbitrarily take the first value, or [GROUP_CONCAT / LIST_AGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html), which can fold string values together with a delimiter. And [PostGres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/xaggr.html) allows you to make your own aggregate functions!. But sadly, none of this in SqlServer, hence MIN()
 / MAX() for now.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

An aggregation function must be specified when using `PIVOT` command because the first step of the pivoting operation is a grouping operation on the column specified in the `FOR` clause that reduces the number of lines of the resulting tables.

The aggregation function is used to manage values for the other columns that are required in the output table.

From [Technet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) documentation:

> PIVOT rotates a table-valued expression by turning the unique values
>   from one column in the expression into multiple columns in the output,
>   and **performs aggregations where they are required on any remaining
>   column values that are wanted in the final output**.

Here is the `PIVOT` command syntax taken from the same Technet article:

```
SELECT <non-pivoted column>,  
    [first pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    [second pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    ...  
    [last pivoted column] AS <column name>  
FROM  
    (<SELECT query that produces the data>)   
    AS <alias for the source query>  
PIVOT  
(  
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)  
FOR   
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]   
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],  
    ... [last pivoted column])  
) AS <alias for the pivot table>  
<optional ORDER BY clause>;
```

Please note that after the `PIVOT` clause you must specify an aggregation function:

```
...
<aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)
...
```

For an additional insight on this topic see also [this](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2233325&seqNum=4) Microsoft Press article.