# How to select different records as columns in a view implemented in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

Consider the following table schema

```
Employee(Id int primary key,Name varchar(255))

EquipMent(Id int primary key ,EquipmentName varchar(255))

EquipmentMapping(Id int primary key,EmployeeId varchar(255),EquipmentId int)
```

Consider the following data present in these tables as

```
Employee
(Id,Name)
(1,Jhon)
(2,Max)


EquipMent
(Id,EquipmentName)
(1,Hammer)
(2,Axe)
(3,Screw Driver)


EquipmentMapping
(Id,EmployeeId,EquipmentId)
(1,1,1)
(2,1,2)
(3,2,1)
```

I want to create a view which will have the following schema as

```
EmployeeEquipmentMappingView(Id int identity(1,1),EmployeeId int,Equipment1Id int,EquipMent2Id int)
```

Here the constraints are the employee cannot have more than 2 equipment mapped against him.

I want to select these two equipment mapped against him in Equipment1Id and EquipMent2Id columns.

The output will look like

```
Select * from EmployeeEquipmentMappingView
(Id ,EmployeeId ,Equipment1Id ,EquipMent2Id )
(1,1,1,2)
(2,2,1,NULL)
```

Comment: @SQL_M   I am trying to figure it out I am a noob in  SQL.

Comment: Start here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx, then go here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343145/tsql-pivot-without-aggregate-function

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @PivotColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @PivotSelectColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column
SELECT @PivotColumnNames= ISNULL(@PivotColumnNames + ',','')
+ QUOTENAME(EquipmentId)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EquipmentId FROM EquipmentMapping) AS EquipmentId
--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column with isnull
SELECT @PivotSelectColumnNames 
    = ISNULL(@PivotSelectColumnNames + ',','')
    +  QUOTENAME(EquipmentId) +' AS '
    + QUOTENAME('Equipment' + convert(varchar(10), EquipmentId) + 'id')
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EquipmentId FROM EquipmentMapping) AS EquipmentId
--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic
SET @DynamicPivotQuery =
N'SELECT EmployeeId, ' + @PivotSelectColumnNames + '
From (
     select  EmployeeId,
             EquipmentId
     from EquipmentMapping
     ) x
PIVOT(MAX(EquipmentId)
FOR EquipmentId IN (' + @PivotColumnNames + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

[Live sample](http://rextester.com/SHDG80176)