# How to Deduplicate an id column by adding an overflow column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

Alright guys I need some help! I am need to duplicate the `ID` Column and I'm having trouble with adding a column without loosing important data. 
Is there a way to make an `"overflow column"` that would take the secondary `[tags]` and put them into a new column?

Here is the example:

```
 **UniqueId**           **Age**     **Zip***              **Tag**
    1                      20          11111               yellow
    2                      25          33333                blue
    2                      25          33333               black
    3                      30          44444               purple
    3                      30          44444                pink
    3                      30          44444                white
```

This is what i want the output to look like

```
  **UniqueId**          **Age**     **Zip***    **Tag1**  **Tag2**  **Tag3**
    1                      20          11111      yellow     NULL      NULL
    2                      25          33333       blue      black     NULL
    3                      30          44444      purple     pink     white
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: If there are only a change of 3 duplicates, then you can use a window function and aggregation, otherwise I'd use a Dynamic Pivot. Can you specify? Note, if it's N number of duplicates then you can google dynamic pivot and find tons of examples

Comment: Just some hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891683/how-do-you-use-transpose-the-following-table-in-sql/49893943#49893943

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you now the maximum number of tags, you can use `pivot` or conditional aggregation:

```
select t.uniqueid, t.age, t.zip,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then tag end) as tag_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then tag end) as tag_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then tag end) as tag_2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by uniqueid order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by t.uniqueid, t.age, t.zip;
```

Answer (score 4):

Though I tend to prefer conditional aggregations as Gordon illustrated... they offer a bit more flexibilty.

You can do a simple PIVOT

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select UniqueID
              ,Age
              ,Zip
              ,Tag
              ,Col = concat('Tag',Row_Number() over (Partition By UniqueId order by Tag) )
         From YourTable
       ) A 
 Pivot (Max(Tag) for Col in ([Tag1],[Tag2],[Tag3],[Tag4]) ) p
```

**Returns**

```
UniqueID    Age Zip     Tag1    Tag2    Tag3    Tag4
1           20  11111   yellow  NULL    NULL    NULL
2           25  33333   black   blue    NULL    NULL
3           30  44444   pink    purple  white   NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

**attention**: Do not store the age as an int number! Rather store a DOB and compute the age...

This is not a real answer to your question, but the thing you should rather do:

To be honest: Your question can be solved (and there are good answers already), but you should not do this.
Whenever you feel the need to add numbers to a field's name (Tag1, Tag2...) the design will be wrong (almost ever). Push these values into a related side table (just the Id and the tag), remove the column from your original table and place a foreign key pointing to the new table. Now you can join these values whenever you need them. `PIVOT` (or *conditional aggregation*) is for output only...

This is completely untested, so be careful with your data (backup!), but something along these lines should work:

```
CREATE TABLE TagTable (ID INT IDENTITY
                      ,FKOriginal INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_TagTable_OriginalTable FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES OriginalTable(UniqueId)
                      ,Tag VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);

--an index to support the fk
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TagTable_FKOriginal ON TagTable(FKOriginal);
GO

--shift the existing data
INSERT INTO TagTable --you might use DISTINCT...
SELECT UniqueId,Tag
FROM OriginalTable;
GO

--delete duplicated rows
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UniqueId ORDER BY UniqueId) AS RowId --Find a better sort column if needed
    FROM OriginalTable 
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE RowId>1; --Only the first remains
GO

--throw away the tag column in the original table
ALTER TABLE OriginalTable DROP COLUMN Tag;
GO

--See the result via JOIN-Select
SELECT *
FROM OriginalTable AS o
INNER JOIN TagTable AS t ON o.UniqueId=t.FKOriginal;
```

If you need these pivoted columns, you can use the approaches provided in other answers with the final `SELECT` too.

Comment: Completely glossed over the the AGE bit.  Great eye.