# Select rows as different columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table with following structure:

[image]

I want to show it like this:

[image]

Maximum 5 users will be there per LocIC and AuditID

Comment: This has been asked and answered thousands of times on SO and probably close to a million times around the rest of the internet. Look for either PIVOT or crosstab.

Comment: Here's one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50218241/sql-how-do-i-transpose-and-group-data-into-static-columns/50218653#50218653

Comment: @SeanLange Pivot questions should be restricted on SO.

Comment: @dfundako I agree. It is crazy how many times a day the same question like this one comes in.

Comment: Have you tried Google????  There are tons of example on this!!!

Comment: Who would upvote this silly question???  This shows no effort and should be downvoted instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want *conditional* aggregation:

```
select LocID, AuditID,
       max(case when Seq = 1 then userID end) User1,
       max(case when Seq = 2 then userID end) User2,
       max(case when Seq = 3 then userID end) User3,
       max(case when Seq = 4 then userID end) User4,   
       max(case when Seq = 5 then userID end) User5   
from (select *,
              row_number() over (partition by LocID, AuditID order by userID) Seq
      from table a 
     ) t
group by LocID, AuditID;
```

Comment: Thank you Yogesh for your valuable help

Answer (score -3):

You can use group_concat feature SQL server.

select LocID,AuditID, group_concat(userID) listUser from table group by LocID, AuditID

Here later you can use listUser column values to show in table

Comment: There is no group_concat in sql server. There is a STRING_AGG function added but not until sql server 2017 and many people are not upgraded that much yet.

Comment: Besides, `GROUP_CONCAT` or `STRING_AGG` has nothing to do with  converting rows to columns. That's pivoting