# How can I use SQL Pivot Table to turn my rows of data into columns

Tags: sql, pivot

In `SQL 2008`, I need to flatten a table and show extra rows as columns. All I can find are queries with calculations. I just want to show the raw data. The data is like as below (simplified):

```
ID#     Name       Name_Type
1       Mary Jane  Legal
1       MJ         Nickname
1       Smith      Maiden
2       John       Legal
3       Suzanne    Legal
3       Susie      Nickname
```

I want the data to show as:

```
ID#     Legal      Nickname      Maiden
1       Mary Jane  MJ            Smith
2       John
3       Suzanne    Susie
```

where nothing shows in the column if there is not a row existing for that column. I'm thinking the `Pivot Table` method should work.

Comment: There are 1000000 examples of using PIVOT what exactly did you try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TSQL Pivot without aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343145/tsql-pivot-without-aggregate-function)

Answer (score 0):

[PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) requires you to use an aggregate. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343145/tsql-pivot-without-aggregate-function) for a better explanation of how it works.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable
(
    ID# INT
    , Name VARCHAR(50)
    , Name_Type VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES
(1, 'Mary Jane', 'Legal')
, (1, 'MJ', 'Nickname')
, (1, 'Smith', 'Maiden')
, (2, 'John', 'Legal')
, (3, 'Suzanne', 'Legal')
, (3, 'Susie', 'Nickname');

SELECT * 
FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM #MyTable
    ) AS Names
    PIVOT (MAX(NAME)
    FOR Name_Type IN ([Legal], [Nickname], [Maiden]))
    AS PVT;

DROP TABLE #MyTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (replace "new_Table" with your table - name and "ID_" with your id - column):

```
SELECT ID_ AS rootID, (
SELECT Name
    FROM new_table
        WHERE Name_type = 'legal'
            AND new_table.ID_ = rootID
) AS legal,
(
SELECT Name
    FROM new_table
        WHERE Name_type = 'Nickname'
            AND ID_ = rootID
) AS Nickname,
(
SELECT Name
    FROM new_table
        WHERE Name_type = 'Maiden'
            AND ID_ = rootID
) AS Maiden
FROM new_table
    GROUP BY rootID;
```

Comment: Many good suggestions here. I will try a few. There seem to be many ways to flatten the table. Thanks so much. Appreciated as I am not a programmer but have a very short deadline to extract data from 5 different tables with several one to many relationships that all have to go into a single flat file. After 5 hours of unsuccessful searching, time was running out. Thank you for tolerating my redundant question as time was of the essence.

Comment: Did you try the query ?