# Dynamic TSQL Pivot without aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have a table like this ('ExternalPersonRelationTable')

| PersonId | SubjectCode |
| --- | --- |
| 4187 | 3 |
| 4187 | 278 |
| 4429 | 3 |
| 4429 | 4 |
| 4463 | 99 |
| 4464 | 174 |
| 4464 | 175 |

I want to rotate the data so that every person in the table gets a column and a TRUE/FALSE value for each subject code, i.e. a table like this:

| Code | 4187 | 4429 | 4463 | 4464 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 4 | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 99 | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 174 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 175 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |

I gather this is a problem I should solve using PIVOT and dynamic SQL, but I'm afraid my experience is limited to using CTE's and simple JOINs, so I am having a hard time PIVOTing the data, never mind dynamically naming the resulting columns.

The SubjectCode and PersonId will eventually be joined to other tables in order to fetch their real values, but for the example I think they are unnecessary.

How do I solve this?

Comment: You *can't* pivot without aggregation. Pivoting is a form of aggregation.

Comment: From what I've read it's possible to use the MAX aggregation function (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1343164/9323877) to accomplish not aggregating. But notwithstanding that, if that is barking up the wrong tree, how would I go about solving the problem?

Comment: `MAX` is an aggregate function.

Comment: I apologize for the impreciseness of the question :)

Comment: I really wouldn't go down the road of a dynamic pivot, especially if you don't know procedural T-SQL that well. It requires dynamic SQL, which is itself difficult to write and debug, and is prone to errors and injection. Column names should be renamed in the client application. Instead use a rownumber pivot, so your column names become `Person1,Person2,Person3...` this is much easier to do and does not require dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample data**

```
create table ExternalPersonRelationTable
(
  PersonId int,
  SubjectCode int
);

insert into ExternalPersonRelationTable (PersonId, SubjectCode) values
(4187, 3),
(4187, 278),
(4429, 3),
(4429, 4),
(4463, 99),
(4464, 174),
(4464, 175);
```

**Solution**

Start with a (limited) static version of the pivot query as a reference.

```
select piv.SubjectCode as Code,
       isnull(convert(bit, piv.[4187]), 0) as [4187],
       isnull(convert(bit, piv.[4429]), 0) as [4429],
       isnull(convert(bit, piv.[4463]), 0) as [4463],
       isnull(convert(bit, piv.[4464]), 0) as [4464]
from ExternalPersonRelationTable epr
pivot (max(epr.PersonId) for epr.PersonId in ([4187],[4429],[4463],[4464])) piv;
```

Identify the dynamic parts and construct (and validate) those.

```
-- constuct lists
declare @fieldList nvarchar(1000);
declare @pivotList nvarchar(1000);

with cte as
(
  select epr.PersonId
  from ExternalPersonRelationTable epr
  group by epr.PersonId
)
select @fieldList = string_agg('isnull(convert(bit, piv.['
                             + convert(nvarchar(10), cte.PersonId)
                             + ']), 0) as ['
                             + convert(nvarchar(10), cte.PersonId)
                             + ']', ', ') within group (order by cte.PersonId),
       @pivotList = string_agg('['
                             + convert(nvarchar(10), cte.PersonId)
                             + ']', ',') within group (order by cte.PersonId)
from cte;

-- validate lists
select @fieldList as FieldList;
select @pivotList as PivotList;
```

Merge the dynamic parts in the final query (and validate during development phase).

```
-- construct query
declare @query nvarchar(3000) = 'select piv.SubjectCode as Code, '
                              + @fieldList
                              + 'from ExternalPersonRelationTable epr '
                              + 'pivot (max(epr.PersonId) for epr.PersonId in ('
                              + @pivotList
                              + ')) piv;';
      
-- validate query
select @query as Query;
```

Run the dynamic query.

```
-- run query
exec sp_executesql @query;
```

**Result**

```
Code  4187   4429   4463   4464
----  -----  -----  -----  -----
  3   True   True   False  False
  4   False  True   False  False
 99   False  False  True   False
174   False  False  False  True
175   False  False  False  True
278   True   False  False  False
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=da0c9beaeee1bd2db28225d9471d5413) to see things in action.