# How to pivot table without using aggregate function SQL?

Tags: sql, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to pivot table, but to use PIVOT() have to use any aggregation functions such as max(), min(), mean(), count(), sum(). I don't need use these functions, but I need to transform my table without using them.

Source table

| SOURCE | ATTRIBUTE | CATEGORY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GOOGLE | MOVIES | 1 |
| YAHOO | JOURNAL | 2 |
| GOOGLE | MUSIC | 1 |
| AOL | MOVIES | 3 |

The new table should be like this:

| ATTRIBUTE | GOOGLE | YAHOO | AOL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MOVIES | 1 |  | 3 |

Will be grateful if someone would help me.

Comment: could you please also add the desired output?

Comment: @Sergey I tried to add the desired output, but something went wrong with markdown. Now jarlh added the one row for desired output. Thanks.

Comment: If you consider your data, you will see that an aggregation is required. You start out with multiple rows where ATTRIBUTE = 'MOVIES' but your output requires a single row. You are 'aggregating' by ATTRIBUTE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TSQL Pivot without aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343145/tsql-pivot-without-aggregate-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pivot syntax requires an aggregate function. It's not optional.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html

> SELECT ... FROM ...    PIVOT ( <aggregate_function> ( <pivot_column> )
> FOR <value_column> IN ( <pivot_value_1> [ , <pivot_value_2> ... ] ) )
>
> [ ... ]

In the Snowflake documentation, optional syntax is in square braces. The `<aggregate_function>` is not in square braces, so it's required. If you only have one value, any of the aggregate functions you listed except count will work and give the same result.

```
create or replace table T1("SOURCE" string, ATTRIBUTE string, CATEGORY int);

insert into T1("SOURCE", attribute, category) values
('GOOGLE',  'MOVIES',   1),
('YAHOO',   'JOURNAL',  2),
('GOOGLE',  'MUSIC',    1),
('AOL',     'MOVIES',   3);

select *
from T1
   PIVOT ( sum ( CATEGORY )
            for "SOURCE" in ( 'GOOGLE', 'YAHOO', 'AOL' ));
```

| ATTRIBUTE | 'GOOGLE' | 'YAHOO' | 'AOL' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MOVIES | 1 | null | 3 |
| MUSIC | 1 | null | null |
| JOURNAL | null | 2 | null |

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach utilising [ARRAY_AGG()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html) which maybe more flexible.  For example if you wanted to pivot the Attribute instead of the category, easy peasy. The 'category' here appears to be more of a classification or label instead of something we'd want summed.

[image]

The array doesn't need to be constrained any particular data type. [This can be extended to pivots with many objects.](https://medium.com/@adrian.white/pivot-multiple-values-in-sql-with-snowflake-5d570636a352)

[image]

```
WITH CTE AS (  SELECT 'GOOGLE' SOURCE, 'MOVIES' ATTRIBUTE, 1 CATEGORY UNION ALL SELECT 'YAHOO', 'JOURNAL', 2 UNION ALL SELECT 'GOOGLE', 'MUSIC', 1 UNION ALL SELECT 'AOL', 'MOVIES', 3 );

SELECT
    ATTRIBUTE, GOOGLE[0] GOOGLE, YAHOO[0] YAHOO, AOL[0] AOL 
FROM
    CTE PIVOT (ARRAY_AGG(CATEGORY) FOR SOURCE IN ('GOOGLE', 'YAHOO', 'AOL')
) AS A (ATTRIBUTE, GOOGLE, YAHOO, AOL);
```